# Does method overloading make code more readable?

Tags: java

I have read on many blogs and website that method overloading make code more readable:

> Method overloading increases the readability of the program.([Source](http://www.javatpoint.com/method-overloading-in-java))

where as official documentation say:

> [Overloaded methods should be used sparingly, as they can make code
>   much less readable.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

Comment: Opinions. Opinions everywhere.

Comment: It depends. It can make it easier to read and remember, or it can make your API confusing e.g. `List<Integer>.remove(x)`

Comment: On a related note: overloading constructors can help, but they can also be confusing (in which case factory methods would be better)

Comment: Readability is so much in the eye of the beholder that it's hard to introduce much objectivity in its discussion.

Comment: You can say this of many substances your body needs for daily life. Too much of them is lethal, too little causes malnutrition

Comment: `StringBuilder.append` I think is a good example of overloading and `List.remove` is a poor example.

Comment: Opinion based. Helps to reduce long method names, e.g. `myList.removeByIndex(i)` and `myList.removeByObject(o)` and instead allows methods with the same/similar functionality to accept different parameter types. On the flip side it requires determining which method was actually called, but this should be fairly obvious in my most cases.

Comment: Yes I agree with the documentation. Method overloading is basically used to keep with consistancy of naming methods BUT at the cost ambiguity.

Comment: I believe method overloading does make code less readable, because of hidden semantic. Read this blog post of mine about this very topic: [The Hidden Dangers of Method Overloading](https://www.yegor256.com/2023/08/01/method-overloading.html)

Answer (score 3):

In that case you have to do some observation to come to the conclusions

Which is better?

**Case 1**

```
System.out.print(“Hello”); 
System.out.print(12);
```

OR

**Case 2**

```
System.out.printString(“Hello”);
System.out.printInt(12);
```

As seen **Case 1** is more readable and can be remember easily in comparison to **Case 2 .** This above **Case 1** print method is overloaded as seen in [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/PrintStream.java#PrintStream.print%28long%29) . So thats why java creator dint implement **Case 2.** 
Hence ill go with **overloading is more readable** and also if its not readable then java developers would have implemented **Case 2**.

Comment: I've upvoted... Good explanation.. :)